# Transfer reputation from account with different email

Tags: support, merge-accounts

I left my last job on less than friendly terms.

I had an account using my company email account, which I can no longer access.

Is there anyway to recover my reputation points?

Comment: Since you have no access to the old email address, I'm not sure [merging](https://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts) is an option for you. You may need to live with your new identity. But you get two very important lessons for the future: do not use company accounts for personal stuff, and try not to burn bridges when changing jobs.

Comment: Even if you do not have access to the old email address, you should still have access to your old SO account, right? Why not login to SO with that account and change the email address on your profile settings?

Comment: You'd probably need to prove that you have access to your other account. Use the "contact us" link in the site footer to contact admins. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts

Comment: @yivi Doesn't a change of the email address usually send a confirmation email to the old address requiring you to allow that step? Doesn't SO do that as well?

Comment: @Tom I don't know if it "usually" involves that. It depends on the provider, and what does it want to prioritize. Requiring confirmation on the old email adress can be seen as some sort of "extra" security, but doing it that way can lead to this kind of situation. And blocking changing email address could be too little, too late, if they already were able to access you account. I have no clue how SO does it, haven't changed my e-mail address ever, I think.

Answer (score 1):

I will try to merge. Thanks @SamuelLiew and @yivi.

Point taken about not using my work email for my profile. Won't make the mistake again.

Comment: Actually I got to know you didn't find a solution since the rep was still 99. What was your old account?

Comment: It would have been mchassy@leftshiftit.com. But I can't access that email anymore so it doesn't really matter.

Comment: Hmm. Do you want revenge? Maybe I can destroy that company for you. I don't like it when small companies harrass their employees like that. I'm MARSK, btw.

Comment: They did much worse than that, but don't worry, my plan for their destruction is already in place ;-)